# Rigging is moving part of mesh in unwanted way

Tags: rigging

The spine is moving odly at the higher part - the mesh is stretching and I don't want it. How to change it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, hard to know, maybe share your file (the armature only if it has to do with the armature)

Comment: @moonboots how do I share the file here?

Comment: in weight paint mode hold shift and click in an area that is doing weird stuff. It should show you all groups the vertex belongs to. Odds are that some vertices are in groups they are not supposed to be in.

Comment: try https://blend-exchange.com/ if it's too heavy use another platform like workupload.com

Comment: @moonboots I edited the post with the link

Comment: Your goal is a rig or straightening spine? To make model straight you can create a curve along spine, add a strip deformed by Curve modifier, select model and assign Surface Deform modifier with Target to Strip, Bind it and disable Curve modifier for strip ... so your model becomes straight.

Answer (score 4):

So it doesn't look like the bones are stretching, it's rather the mesh that is stretched, because these vertices are part of vertex groups that they should not be part of. When you parented you should have kept a straight mesh, not spiraled, so that they were no risk of bad vertex group assignment, so either straighten your mesh and armature and parent again, or here is a quick (but not ideal) fix:

Remove these vertices from the groups they should not be part of:

[image]

Then select the armature in *Object* mode, shift select the mesh, switch to *Weight Paint mode*, select the front bones, then *Weights > Assign Automatic from Bones*:

[image]